# Spring Hateoas Ignoring Query Parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Spring Hateoas is not creating the appropriate link for the following request mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/member/{id}")
public MemberResource getMemberById(@RequestParam String id){
     Member member = MemberService.getMemberById(id);
     return new MemberResource(member);
}


public class MemberResource extends ResourceSupport{

     public MemberResource(Member member){
  add(linkTo(methodOn(MemberController.class).getMember(member.getId)).withSelfRel());
        add(linkTo(methodOn(TeamsController.class).getTeams(memberId)).withRel("teams"));
        }}


        @GetMapping("/teams")
        public List<TeamResource> getTeamsById(@RequestParam String id)          {
            List<Team> teams = teamService.getTeamsById(id);
            return teams.stream().map(TeamResource::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

When calling /member/12345 would expect to to return:

```
{
     member: {
       //omitted for brevity
     },
    _links:[
       {
         href: .../members/12345
       },
       {
```

> ```
>          href: ../teams?memberId = 12345
> ```

```
       }

      ]
}
```

But instead it returns:

```
{
     member: {
       //omitted for brevity
     },
    _links:[
       {
         href: .../members/12345
       },
       {
```

> ```
>          href: ../teams/12345
> ```

```
       }

      ]
}
```

Why is this? It is completely ignoring the filter even though I am using @RequestParam. Any advice is appreciated in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: never used Spring HATEOAS.

But at first glance it looks like you're mixing up two URL-Parameter types:

- `@PathVariable` for Path variables like `.../teams/TEAM_ID`
- `@RequestParam` for Query Parameters like `.../teams?id=TEAM_ID`

Comment: And the reason for your disclaimer?